# How to show related nodes in a view block based on taxonomy terms?

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have two Content Type, Apartments and Events.
Both have a Term reference field (field_location).

I want make a view block that displays in the nodes of Apartments Content Type some fields of Events Content Type based on field_location term.
If in Apartments the field_location is Rome the block must display only the field of the nodes Events with field_location Rome.

How I can do it?

Thank you in advance.

> **SOLVED**

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

- Add a Contextual Filter->Has Taxonomy Term ID
- **When the filter value is NOT available:**

  - Provide default value Type: Taxonomy term ID from URL
  - Check only: Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks; Limit terms by vocabulary; Vocabulary: my-vocabulary; Filter to items that share my term.
- **When the filter value IS available or default is provided:**
  Check only: Reduce duplicates.